# problems about prime ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $A=\mathbb{Z}[X,Y]/(Y^2-6X^2), B=\mathbb{Z}[X,T]/(T^2-6)$ where $X,Y,T $ are variables and let $x,y$ be the cosets of $X,Y$ in $A$ whilst $x',t$ be the cosets of $X,T$ in $B$.

Consider the ideals $P_1=xA+yA+5A$, $P_2=(x-y)A+5A$, $Q_1=x'B+(t+1)B$.

Show that $P_1, P_2, Q_1$ are prime ideals.

$P_1$ can be done by considering the finitely many elements of  $A/P_1$ and checking it is a prime ideal. As for $P_2$ and $Q_1$ it would appear to be  "intuitively obvious " that any element in $P_2, Q_1$ wouldn't factorize into ones which aren't, but how do I actually show this?

Comment: What is $Z$?  Do you mean the integers?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I've mathbb-ed it.

Comment: Take the quotient of $A$ by $P_1$ and $P_2$ and of $B$ by $Q_1$ and see that the result is an integral domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute the quotient rings:

$A / P_1 \cong {\mathbb Z}[X,Y]/(Y^2 - 6X^2, X, Y, 5) = {\mathbb Z}[X,Y]/(X, Y, 5) \cong {\mathbb Z}_5$.

$A / P_2 \cong {\mathbb Z}[X,Y]/(Y^2 - 6X^2, X - Y, 5) \cong {\mathbb Z}[X]/(X^2 - 6X^2, 5) = {\mathbb Z}[X]/(5) \cong {\mathbb Z}_5[X]$.

$B / Q_1 \cong {\mathbb Z}[X, T]/(T^2 - 6, X, T+1) \cong {\mathbb Z}[T]/(-5, T+1) \cong {\mathbb Z}_5$.

In all three cases, the quotient is an integral domain, so $P_1$, $P_2$, and $Q_1$ are prime ideals.